# JDA Discord - How to get all names of Users who reacted to a bot's message in an array

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

I am trying to code a giveaway bot.  I am having problems getting all Usernames of Users who reacted to the Giveaway Message that have been sent by the bot and store them in a `Array` of Type `String`.

Comment: Show us what you done and tell us how you get data from a discord bot.

Comment: @stackstack293 I Use `event.getChannel` or `event.getMessage`

Comment: @stackstack293 I Use JDA and Usually `event.getChannel` to get items in that channel or to type a message but i just can't like, Check the reactions of it's message and then store all users in a array of type string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `Message` object of the message by getting the history of the channel its in and then get the message by id from the history.

The `Message` object has a `getReactions` method that returns a list of all reactions on a message, you can then iterate through the reactions and in turn then iterate thru all the users that reacted on the given reaction and save the name/id of each user who reacted into an array or list or data structure of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<MessageReaction> reactionsList = event.event.getMessage().getReactions();

// List of users that reacted to every possible emote.
for (int i = 0; i < reactionsList.size(); i++)
{
    List<User> users = reactionsList.get(i).retrieveUsers().complete();
}
```